# Get all positions of regexp matches in string

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

How do I store the positions of all regexp matches in a string using elisp?  Here is an example where I want to get the positions of all the ends of words/numbers in the string, or if single-quoted, the end of the single quoted phrase.

```
(setq str "1  '2015-08-14 7:11:00'     GAR -0.29 89.10 -0.2795       0.375       8 0.6026 155.430000000          'GA Obler' 2015-08-14")

(string-match "\\b" str -1)  ; gets the last match
```

So, this example should return a list of (1, 23, etc).  I feel like I must be missing some function that does global matching?  Or, maybe it's necessary to use a while loop and search forward/backward.

#### Edit

I ended up writing this function, but my elisp is terrible so the question is still, is this the proper way to do this - or is there an alternative builtin function that does this already?

```
(defun match-positions (regexp str)
  (let ((res '()) (pos 0))
    (while (and (string-match regexp str pos)
        (< pos (length str) ) )
      (let ((m (match-end 0)))
    (push m res)
    (setq pos m)
    ) )
    (nreverse res)
    )
  )
(match-positions "\'.*?\'\\|[-0-9.A-Za-z]+" str)
; (1 23 31 37 43 51 63 71 78 92 112 123)
```

Comment: I don't believe there's a built-in way to do what you want.  Your code looks appropriate, though the checking of `(< os (length str))` should be redundant b/c `string-match` would have already returned `nil` when no match was found.  That and lisp style is to close parens on the last line of the expression, not on lines all by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`match-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Match-Data.html):

```
(setq str "1  '2015-08-14 7:11:00'     GAR -0.29 89.10 -0.2795       0.375       8 0.6026 155.430000000          'GA Obler' 2015-08-14")

(save-match-data
    (and (string-match "\\b" str)
         (let ((first_match (match-string 0 str))
               (second_match (match-string 1 str))
              )
           ;; your code
          )))
```

Comment: Does this only find one match?  I don't really follow how this gives the matches